# Send string array with FormData in swagger C# .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, multipartform-data, swagger-2.0

My .net api signature is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResult>> SendEmail([FromForm]SendEmailModel model)
```

and follows is my swagger config:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "App-Service"       
    });
});

.
.
.

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.DocumentTitle = "App Service";
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "App Service");
});
app.UseMvc();
```

It generates something as follows:

[image: swagger]

But when ever I execute it, `To` parameter send as

```
[
  "\"1\",\"2\",\"3\""
]
```

But it must be:

```
[
  "1", "2", "3"
]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try with formbody indtead of formform?, may be in that case you have json format, instead of sending form you can send jsonboject to controller

Comment: I have to use `FormData` because of uploading file to attach in email

Answer (score 0):

It's better to change the contract to [FromBody] Like Vinit Patel said. But if that's not an option, you'd have to do something hacky to your SendEmailModel model like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResult>> SendEmail([FromForm]SendEmailModel model)
{
    model.To = Regex.Replace(model.To.FirstOrDefault(), "\"", string.Empty)
            .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.None);

    //now you can loop through model.To as a string array
    foreach (string toEmail in model.To)
    {
            // Your logic here
    }
    ...
}
```

It's probably not the best solution, but I hope it helps :)